# Gtk toolbar refuse to show GtkToolButton

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk3

I want to display an GtkToolButton in a GtkToolbar, but no matter what I have tried, the GtkToolButton refuses to show up.

I tried to add tool tip to toolbar, the tool tip did show up when mouse stops on it, so I think it's not the toolbar that didn't show up. I also tried using search engine, but the result returned contains little information.

Where is my mistake? Please help! It's really frustrating sitting here and can't find a solution for a simple task like this...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget   *window;

GtkToolItem *tool_item;
GtkWidget   *toolbar;
GtkBuilder *builder;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv); 

    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file ("test.glade");
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "main_window"));
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to get window\n");
        return 0;
    }

    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    toolbar = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "toolbar"));
    if (toolbar == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to get toolbar from glade file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    GtkWidget *icon = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name("computer", GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);
    tool_item = gtk_tool_button_new(icon, "computer");
    
    gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), tool_item, 0);
    gtk_toolbar_set_icon_size(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR);
    
    gtk_toolbar_set_style(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), GTK_TOOLBAR_BOTH_HORIZ);

    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The Glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main_window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkToolbar" id="toolbar">
            <property name="width_request">361</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">48</property>
            <property name="y">17</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Use `gtk_widget_show_all` instead. Also try to avoid GtkFixed, use GtkBox and GtkGrid instead

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev gtk_widget_show_all solved my problem. Thank you! I was planning to turn to QT for my project before seeing your answer.  Thanks again...